# OpenStack load balancer vs nginx

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, openstack

We are trying to deploy a web application on cloud. We are using OpenStack to host the services. We would want to use load balancer.
OpenStack provides load balancer as a service. I am interested to know if there is any benefit of using NginX as load balancer over OpenStack's LBaaS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LBaaS in our case is HAProxy. Makes things simpler and faster for it operates within OpenStack.

OpenSource nginx works on http layer*. Could do more sophisticated operations based on HTTP traffic.

*- I know commercial version could do more; sticking to free version.

Ref:

1. http://blog.metrink.com/httpd-vs-nginx-vs-haproxy/
2. https://www.quora.com/Which-software-load-balancer-is-better-HAProxy-or-nginx